# multiple Sequelize instances on single database

Tags: node.js, namespaces, sequelize.js

I have few microservices using **Sequelize** as an ORM. 
For simplicity I want all of then to share a single database even though they have nothing in common.

I need each microservice to have:

- Its own Sequelize migration table so I can use rollback function safely.
- Each table needs a namespace according to microservice name. For example `ms1_table1`, `ms1_table2`

I havn't found anything relevant in docs or Google. Any idea or package for that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to divide the single Db into multiple schemas (each for a Micro Service or so - it's also a good practice to start with this separation).
Then, Sequelize has schema support (in constructor function you pass it in options.schema - default is 'public').

Try to look in [sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/) for further information about schema.

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default sequelize stores migration meta information in a table inside the same database. This is the primary road blocker for you.

You can prefer to use a different table name for each service

```
    {
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "MySQL", 

    // Use a different table name. Default: SequelizeMeta
    "migrationStorageTableName": "sequelize_meta",

    // Use a different schema for the SequelizeMeta table
    "migrationStorageTableSchema": "custom_schema"
  }
}
```

This helps in having isolated migration acts for each microservice though all come in the same database